# Luna eclipse 42T chain ring and Shimano Linkglide is there a chain that fits both?

Tags: chain, cassette, chainring, electric-bike, linkglide

My cargo e-bike has a Luna Eclipse 42T chainring with a narrow-wide pattern. Lunacycles states the chainring will work with any 8, 9 or 10 speed chain and that an 11 or 12 speed chain will not work. I assume the higher speed chains are too narrow internally and will either not fit or not release under load. My bike needs new derailleur, cassette and shifter. I was thinking of going for the 10 speed Shimano Deore Linkglide group set. I think it would be a great fit for my use as they claim long durability and easy shifting under load. The chain in this set is 10/11 speed. Shimano also states that the Linkglide set is not compatible with other groups, but not why. They do say that each cog on the cassette is thicker, but is the spacing also different? Or is it wider overall? Is there another Linkglide compatible chain that would fit my chainring? Would using a different chain that happens to fit defeat the purpose of installing Linkglide components to begin with?

What is the internal width between an outer and an inner link in the Linkglide and a regular 10 speed and 11 speed chain?

Sometimes I wish manufacturers could just list sizes and tolerances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linkglide chain is basically 11-speed chain and will likely not have the internal clearance needed for your ring.

The Linkglide 10 cassette and RD will take any 10-speed chain, so that's how you'd do it. I don't really know either way whether or how much this would defeat the purpose, but Linkglide more than anything is a cassette design so I think there would likely be some benefit.

Linkglide 10 and 11 both have unique cog spacing, and the RD and shifters accordingly have unique cable pull. Those are the elements that must be present together.

[image]